# how to place php variables in OOP array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am new to OOP,     I see a sample of code like this:

```
$mp->people->set(12345, array(
'$first_name'       => "John",
'$last_name'        => "Doe"
));
```

How can I use regular php variable in this OOP code... for example:

```
$userid = 12345;
$firstname = "john";
$lastname = "doe";
```

for example (this doesn't work)

```
$mp->people->set($userid, array(
'$first_name'       => "$firstname",
'$last_name'        => "$lastname"
));
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use [double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). I'm not sure if I got the question right. You'll have to use them either in this was if you want to have to keys replaced by variable values:

```
$mp->people->set(12345, array(
    "$first_name"       => "John",
    "$last_name"        => "Doe"
));
```

or just assign the values of the variables if you want the values replaced by them:

```
$mp->people->set(12345, array(
    'first_name'       => $first_name,
    'last_name'        => $last_name
));
```

Comment: i think the keys are actually strings. Doesn't he want to set the values with variables?

Comment: no, I don't think you understood the question correctly, or I don't understand your answer.. I don't want to assign the array value to the PHP variable, I want to assign the value of the php variable to the array in OOP...    

like the $userID, $firstname, etc...

Comment: I think you missing at least a minimal understanding of what `OOP` means. However, check my update it should contain what you want.

Comment: and what about the id  12345.... do I just place the variable :
people->set($userid, array(...